# Unable to start Glassfish 3.1 even though port not occupied

Tags: java, linux, glassfish-3

I'm having trouble starting `Glassfish 3.1` on a newly setup Debian "Squeeze" server. This is a testing server that has been setup and the `Glassfish` installation was copied from a working server to this other server.

I tried running:

```
# ./asadmin start-domain
There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.
Command start-domain failed.
```

I also tried restarting the domain because I thought maybe it was running:

```
# ./asadmin restart-domain
Server is not running, will attempt to start it...
There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.
Command restart-domain failed.
```

At this point I confirmed that `Glassfish` was not running so I checked to see if port 4848 was occupied:

```
# netstat -aon | grep 4848
```

which returned nothing.

I have suspicion that `Glassfish` was copied from the source server while `Glassfish` was still running. Maybe there is some sort of pid file or lock file that was copied over as well.

Any suggestions on how to get `Glassfish` to start?

**Edit**

Here's the `server.log` file from `domain1` after executing the `asadmin start-domain` command:

```
Sep 12, 2011 11:18:02 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
INFO: JVM invocation command line:
/opt/glassfish3/jdk/bin/java
-cp
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-XX:NewRatio=2
-Xmx512m
-client
-javaagent:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Djava.security.policy=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish
-Djava.ext.dirs=/opt/glassfish3/jdk/lib/ext:/opt/glassfish3/jdk/jre/lib/ext:/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Djava.library.path=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/lib:/opt/glassfish3/jdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/opt/glassfish3/jdk/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/glassfish3/jdk/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-domainname
domain1
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains,,,domain1
-instancename
server
-verbose
false
-debug
false
-asadmin-classpath
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/modules/admin-cli.jar
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain
-upgrade
false
-type
DAS
-domaindir
/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
```

Comment: How did you install Glassfish?

Comment: is IPV6 activated on your host?  You should also check the server.log file in the domain directory (often `domain1/logs/server.log` as it might contain more detailed info.

Comment: @Andrew Someone else did the installation. I believe we installed Glassfish by downloading the a tar and extracting it to /opt/glassfish3 on the source server. This test server we copied the folder directly.

Comment: @fvu No IPv6 isn't enabled on the host. Thanks for the suggestion to look at the log. I posted it above. Nothing out of the ordinary that I can tell.

Comment: @Mark not even a hint in the log that it might have encountered a problem during startup. very odd.

Comment: @Mark can you run jps and share the results?

Comment: @Preston I ran jps and I'm only seeing the jps process ID. Nothing else.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First of all check the $HOSTNAME and the etc/hosts file configuration , not try to find a problem with ps aux or netstat -aon .

```
> echo $HOSTNAME
```

response > server (or etc)

```
> cat /etc/hosts
```

in response if you cannot see "$HOSTNAME" after 127.0.0.1 then add it end of the string .
Try again to execute the start-domain command.

Comment: For details of how Glassfish tries to bind the port, see the bug on this issue: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-11489

Comment: More generally, the hostname must resolve to one of the IP addresses for your server. You can the name resolution using `getent hosts <your hostname here>`, and list interfaces and their IPs using `ifconfig`.

Comment: After 5 years since this answer and now this helped me a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Check your /etc/hosts file if the current hostname translates to a valid IP address.
I think something is misconfigured or simple the IP do not exists.

When I changed it back (in my situation) to the 127.0.0.1 address (of course it could be any other but working and attached IP address), the glassfish could be started properly again.

Answer (score 1):

Small chance: Close Netbeans if it is running and try again.

Comment: I'm running glassfish on a server and invoking it from the command line. I am not using Netbeans on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
ps aux | grep glassfish
```

to see if other instances are running?

Comment: I tried executing that command and it shows that glassfish is not running.

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work, at least it doesn't with version 2.  For version 2 it's `ps aux | grep PELaunch` you need.  In Mark's case grep glassfish would work by accident, because his glassfish installation dir is /opt/glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

the problem that  the file /etc/host  havent PC name with IP
add this line in the file.

ip_PC name_PC
192.144.168.2 miserver

This works

http://jvm-java.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/glassfish-v3-linux-process-already.html

Answer (score 0):

-step 1
    start glassfish
-step 2
    change the hostname

result: error starting glassfish

solution:
1 quit the hostname and just leave localhost

2    start glassfish
3    stop glassfish

4    add the hostname

5    start glassfish
and it works!!!

`$ cat /etc/hosts`
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.1.2 YOURHOSTNAME

`$ glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain`
Waiting for domain1 to start .......
Successfully started the domain : domain1

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this by adding new hostname to /etc/host
this is content of my host file :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mozquito     <--- this is what I add
```

and then try start again your asadmin

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem in centOS when i set hostname for my linux.
set your hostname to localhost , probably your problem will be solved.

command : hostname localhost   or

edit /etc/sysconfig/network file in redHat based linux.

goodluck

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this error, it turned out to be because the machine wasn't connected to the network and so couldn't bind to the IP address that was set in `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (I'm using CentOS).  As soon as I enabled the network (mine is a VM) it worked fine.

So the message was misleading in my case: there wasn't (as far as glassfish could tell) anything listening on port 4848 on the desired IP address, but there was evidently an error when trying to attach to that port because the machine itself wasn't connected to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Recently (only applicable on Amazon Web Services-AWS), I found that launching a server into VPC requires quite a bit of extra configuration (once off) to get started.  A key clue:

```
 nslookup `hostname`
```

should work.  If it doesn't work, that's likely to be the reason.

You can either:
 1) launch a server into EC2-classic 
 2) configure your VPC / host to be able to run the command above successfully.

Hope that helps.