# Glassfish Server start-domain domain1 won't start

Tags: java, glassfish

I recently downloaded Glassfish 4.0 and I want to use it in NetBeans for making some Web Applications, but when I want to start the domain1 (asadmin> start-domain domain1) I keep getting this error:**"There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server"**. Any clue what could be the problem?

Comment: You have the answer in your question *There is a process already using the admin port 4848 -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server*

Comment: It might be because the [hostname isn't the correct one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391466/unable-to-start-glassfish-3-1-even-though-port-not-occupied)

Comment: This  `netstat -tulpn | grep 4848` will help verify the running process

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your system using port 4848 that is why.
when glassfish starts its need three port numbers one for administrations, one for http applications other for https.

so in you system 4848 is already reserved by some program or server.

Or you can change default port number as per your need like below.
type in command prompt.

To change the HTTP port to 10080:

- `asadmin set server.http-service.http-listener.http-listener-1.port=10080`

To change the HTTPS port to 10443:

- `asadmin set server.http-service.http-listener.http-listener-2.port=10443`

To change the administration server port to 14848:

- `asadmin set server.http-service.http-listener.admin-listener.port=14848`

Comment: How can I change the port of Glassfish, or how can I find out what is occupying this port and stop that process?

Comment: in your case that would be domain1.xml file

Comment: I found name="admin-listener" port="4848"... what port should I use instead of 4848 which is a guess default port?

Comment: you may use whatever you like but as your problem it should not be use by your system like 4848

Comment: I tried to change the administration server port to 14848 as you mentioned above but I got this: "Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?".

Comment: The answer from @togomez below is more accurate; at least in my case, and I'm betting for most people.

Answer (score 36):

Glassfish could not resolve the host name. Diagnose the problem (on Linux) as follows:

1. Open a Terminal.
2. Type `hostname`.
3. Type: `ping $(hostname)`

If the ping command fails (could not find the host), then add the host name to `/etc/hosts`. This can be accomplished as follows:

1. Switch to root: `sudo su -`
2. Type: `echo "127.0.0.1  $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts`
3. Kill GlassFish
4. Restart GlassFish

Comment: You are right. I knew it was nothing to do with some other process on port 4848 (nc -l 4848 worked). I added the output of `hostname` on `/etc/hosts` and it worked.

BTW, I was happening both with Glassfish 4.0 and 4.1.

Answer (score 5):

Try `lsof -i:4848` on the terminal.

[image: Imgur]

Kill the java processes listed using the command `kill -9 <PID>`.

If you have a GUI task manager, say like Activity Monitor on OSX, then you can just kill the `java` processes listed there.

Hope this works for anyone facing this problem.

Answer (score 4):

1- Go to the ***config*** folder inside your domain.
(In my case:  C:\Glassfish\glassfish\domains\mydomain\config\  )

2-Open the file domain

3-Update the port number on these three lines:
[image]

4-Restart your domain:

--Note
 For restarting the domain:

1-Open cmd console

2-Navigate yo your domain

3-Execute: asadmin restart-domain mydomain

--I hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

Solution can be this:
in console type:

```
echo $HOSTNAME
```

then make sure the output follows 127.0.0.1 string in

```
/etc/hosts
```

For example:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.myserv.pl
```

Comment: Worked for me because fqdn of my new cloned glassfish server was still pointing to its Old IP.

Comment: Finally a solution. Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Do a

> netstat -aon

from command line and check which process is using your port.
If it's not important, kill it as a quick'n'dirty solution.